# Public networks and VPN

Tags: networking, boot, vpn, reboot

I have Ethernet connection with no internet access which is Private network. I have Broadband connection with internet access which is Public network. Have a look at below image:
[image: Public & Private network]

Above-mentioned networks are my active networks.

Now, if I downloaded and installed  any VPN extension to my browser, how does it affect my Public network? What are the difficulties i would face while booting, rebooting of my ***hp*** Notebook PC?

Comment: What specific VPN will you download? In principle one network connection will not interfere with any other, much less with booting up.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, if I downloaded and installed any VPN extension to my browser, how does it affect my Public network?

Host VPNs do not change anything about the existing networks – they *tunnel* access to the remote network over a regular connection across the public network.

- Browser extension-based "VPNs" actually have no effect on networks at all (they do not have the necessary access for that), instead they intercept the individual HTTP requests. They're really HTTP proxy servers.
- Non-extension-based VPNs install a virtual network adapter that would show up as a *new* network (public/work/private, whichever is most suitable) alongside the physical connections. Any packets sent "through the VPN" would first go through the virtual adapter, where the VPN client app receives them and sends the encapsulated packet through one of the physical adapters towards the tunnel host.

> What are the difficulties i would face while booting, rebooting of my hp Notebook PC?

None. Browser extensions exist entirely within the browser and have no effect on the OS boot process.

Non-extension VPNs install a driver to create the virtual network adapter, but this usually has no negative effect on the boot process (as long as it's a decent quality one like TAP-Windows or Wintun).